# Adding a title to more than one definition list?

Tags: html, semantics

I wish to have multiple definition lists and have a single title for these lists, for example:

```
 //how can I add the title of "Items in fridge"
 <dl>
   <dt>Food:</dt>
   <dd>Eggs</dd>
   <dd>Bacon</dd>
 </dl>
 <dl>
   <dt>Drinks:</dt>
   <dd>Water</dd>
   <dd>Juice</dd>
 </dl>
```

What's the correct way to add an overall `<dt>` to various definition lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand the question correctly, but maybe put them in a `<section>`?

```
<section>
  <h1>Items in Fridge</h1>
  <dl>
    <dt>Food:</dt>
    <dd>Eggs</dd>
    <dd>Bacon</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Drinks:</dt>
    <dd>Water</dd>
    <dd>Juice</dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

*(note: there was another solution in my post originally but, as Alohci pointed out in the comments, it wasn't valid HTML)*

Comment: I don't think that the second example is valid according to WHATWG, The [content model of a `<dl>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element:concept-element-content-model) is `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements, **or** `<div>` elements, not a mixture of both.

Comment: Actually. that's not valid either. The content model of `<div>` is: "If the element is a child of a dl element: one or more dt elements followed by **one or more** dd elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements...", so a `<dt>` on its own doesn't conform.

Comment: Welp, I'm out of ideas then